# Windows Server 2012R2 - Slow external website browsing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Internal websites load normally, pings to the outside are fast and never fail during tests, nslookup for yahoo.com returns result immediately and yet I can't through various browsers get to any website without it taking 20seconds or timing out. Network drivers updated, any thoughts?

Also, using a VPN doesn't fix the issue as it has for some having the same problem.

Comment: Did you run a trace route (tracert.exe /?)

Comment: First off, download chrome. Second, make sure there are no proxy settings configure in the browser.